# Can I scale a RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have an `ImageButton` I created in my `RelativeLayout` `XML` file.
But, when I sign my app, it shows differently on each device. How can I make it match all screen sizes?

Note: I tried to scale it using the scale factor and the `draw` method, but it didn't work.

This is my `Activity` code:

```
public class StartActivity extends Activity  {

    private ImageButton Play;
    private ImageButton Rate;
    private ImageButton Board;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        //set to full screen
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

        Rate = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonRate);
        Rate.setY(55);
        Rate.setX(40);

        Board = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonBoard);
        Board.setY(55);
        Board.setX(75);

        Play = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonPlay);
        Play.setY(60);
        Play.setOnClickListener(imageButtonPlayHandler);
    }

    View.OnClickListener imageButtonPlayHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            StartActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
            StartActivity.this.finish();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_start, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us all the relevant code?

Comment: @WillSheppard yes i just edited it

Comment: if these "different devices" have different screen dpi values, try putting in several dpi images. And those values you input, are they px or dip? if they're px, that also might change the look and feel.

Comment: @TharakaDevinda you mean i need to have more than an image to every button?? with different sizes?

Comment: its the case for images anyway, so buttons ought to be no exception. But, if there's an easier way, I do not know it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is that screens are different sizes **and** have different pixel densities. In other words, you can have 2 phones with the same physical size screen, but one has more pixels than the other (and therefore has a higher pixel density).

This is not clear to you because of code like this:

```
Rate.setY(55);
```

In this case "55" is the number of pixels, and it look different on different screens. On one phone it will appear to be half the size compared to a screen of the same size with twice the pixel density. That's because it has a fixed number of pixels.

You need to use things like `DisplayMetrics` and/or different `drawable` folders for appropriately sized images. You will need more than one image if you do not dynamically calculate the screen size and adjust the image accordingly.

Android does this because it should not assume that an image should simply "scale up" or "scale down" on all screens. If it made that assumption then there are many cases where you would have to do the opposite - tell Android to **not** automatically scale because it would look weird or have unacceptable performance or image quality.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it explains a-lot, However on my "main playing activity" i scaled it using scale factor `public void draw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        final float scaleFactoryX = getWidth()/(WIDTH*1.f);
        final float scaleFactoryY = getHeight()/(HEIGHT*1.f);`  and it worked perfectly! how come it wont work in my enter activity who is way simpler!!

Comment: I'm not sure what `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` are in that code, but it looks like you are scaling them. In the code you posted, you are not.

Comment: The WIDTH and HEIGHT are finale static int that i made, but that not the problem, i can create them in this activity (which I've tried before) but i'm getting red lines under `getHeight()` and `getWidth()` saying "Can't resolve" then! I've tried putting (getWindow) instead! No red lines but it didn't work on testing :/

Comment: I mentioned `DisplayMetrics` for that reason. Check it out.